# Why isnt the append() working in this block of code?

Tags: python, methods, new-operator

I've broken down the pieces of this code individually and it all works fine. Yet the append() method only appends once and then refuses to add anything else. I am absolutely losing my mind over this.

```
x = input("Input Password: ")

epicfail = []

def numberchecker(b):
    return any(i.isdigit() for i in b)

def spacechecker(c):
    return any(o.isspace() for o in c)

def passwordvalidator(a):
    if len(a) < 12:
        epicfail.append("Your password is too short!")
    elif a.islower() == True:
        epicfail.append("Your password contains zero uppercase letters!")
    elif a.isupper() == True:
        epicfail.append("Your password contains zero lowercase letters!")
    elif numberchecker(x) == False:
        epicfail.append("Your password contains zero numbers!")
    elif spacechecker(x) == True:
        epicfail.append("Your password contains a whitespace!")
    return epicfail

print(passwordvalidator(x))
```

I expect the append() method to append to the epicfail list every time it is activated. Yet is only appends once. I have tried breaking down every piece of the code individually and it all works fine.

Comment: As you use elifs, when one condition is met, all the other are ignored. If you want multiple to trigger, just use ifs instead.
Furthermore, you can remove "== True" when you are checking a boolean, and replace "if xxx == False:" by "if not xxx:".

Comment: @charon25 I think you should post an answer with the details you provided in the comment

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I was not sure it was enough to be a whole answer but you are right.

Answer (score 1):

As you use `elif`, when one condition is met, all the others are ignored. If you want multiple to trigger, just use `if` instead.

Furthermore, you can remove "== True" when you are checking a boolean, and replace "if xxx == False:" by "if not xxx:".